# DNS record for SSH (docker)

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh, docker

I have a docker container which bind the port 2222:22. It's possible to connect using `ssh -T sub.example.com -p 2222`.

I'm looking for a way to access ssh the container without specify the port number. I thought this could be done with a DNS record.

I set a DNS record `SRV _ssh._tcp.sub 5 10022 sub.example.com` to my domain in the admin interface of my provider, this does not work.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need clients that actually use SRV records as well and as far as I know none of the (common) SSH clients do ...

Very few common applications/protocols actually support SRV records.

---

Instead: edit your ssh clients configuration file `~/.ssh/config` make an entry for that host and you at least will no longer  have to explicitly specify the port number on the commandline every time you need to connect:

```
#~/.ssh/conf
Host sub.example.com
    HostName sub.example.com
    Port 2222
    ...
```

and then `ssh sub.example.com`

Answer (score 5):

I am using [wrapsrv](https://github.com/farsightsec/wrapsrv) together with `ProxyCommand` and `socat` to use `SRV` records for determination of connection endpoint:

```
Host *.my.domain
        ProxyCommand    wrapsrv _ssh._tcp.%h socat STDIO TCP:%%h:%%p
```

The advantage is that both `scp` and `sftp` should use it from ssh config file.

Please note that `SRV` record needs THREE integers: priority, weight and port, not two as you are showing in your question.

Answer (score 3):

Some people wanted to solve the same issue as you and made a wrapper. I didn't test those tools, but from reading them, they do look up and use the port information. (They might even do more: doing ssh to the name defined in the SRV record, can end up in a different hostname if the record was so defined.). Now supporting other commands (scp, sftp...) or multiple hosts is not supported there.

### [ssh-srv-wrapper.sh](https://gist.github.com/taylor/1372925) (bash)

> Introduction
>
> *ssh-srv-wrapper* is bash shell script which tries to find a SSH SRV
>   record for the first host and uses what is found rather than what was
>   passed (if a valid record is found).

### [sshsrv](https://github.com/Crosse/sshsrv/blob/master/main.go) (go)

> sshsrv is a simple program to lookup and connect to an SSH endpoint
>   via DNS SRV records.