# How to make srv record for ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, port, srv-record

I got the port 2107 for ssh and I want to connect it with ssh.mydomain.se without typing in the port in putty? so is it possible to connect 123.456.78.9:2107 to ssh.mydomain.se?

Comment: Are you asking about clients that support looking up SRV records or how to set them up in DNS? If the latter then you probably need to add more detail about if you are running your own DNS or using a provider.

Comment: A good answer on the topic https://serverfault.com/a/960740/442430

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Putty or the default OpenSSH client support SRV records (though it is [suggested](http://egopoly.com/2008/02/ssh-slow-on-leopard.html) that ssh on OSx does support it).

There are wrapper scripts e.g. [this one](https://gist.github.com/taylor/1372925/3eee302b64a2e9b583f5596b4b4a49de1cf66edc) for the command line OpenSSH client to do the look up first.